# emacs: how to disable .# files creation

Tags: emacs, elisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does emacs create temporary symbolic links for modified files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738170/why-does-emacs-create-temporary-symbolic-links-for-modified-files)

Every time I edit file emacs creates file similar to:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 vladimir vladimir   49 2011-11-23 19:20 .#models.py -> vladimir@host.15570:1322037576
```

I already tried

```
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

but without success. How can I disable such behavior?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of emacs 24.3 it is possible to disable lock files using the the "create-lockfiles" option int the Emacs customization system or by directly setting the create-lockfiles variable to nil:

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

In previous Emacs versions there's no way to disable this functionality through a customization.  You could hack the C code to prevent the links from showing up.  But that's probably more work than you want.

The links are there to serve as file locks, to enable Emacs to recognize when someone else is already editing the file.  See the documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/File-Locks.html) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html#Interlocking).

Comment: emacs disable lock file creation keywords have now been added so google will find it for me when I can't remember how I found it before.