# How to include Emacs '.#' crash-recovery files/symlinks in "redirect" of default autosave-dir?

Tags: emacs, autosave

Currently, I'm able to redirect Emacs backup files (those ending in '~' and those starting in '#') to a central location using the code below (it renames them nicely also, encoding the file path in the file name (e.g., `~/tmp/emacs_autosaves/#!home!cbalz!.bashrc#`).

But how to preserve the functionality in that code, while also moving the files that Emacs makes that start with '.#' (those are often or always symlinks)?

Current working code - needs to be modified or augmented to work with files/symlinks starting with '.#' :

```
(defvar autosave-dir
 (concat "~/tmp/emacs_autosaves/" (user-login-name) "/"))
(make-directory autosave-dir t)
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `(("\\(?:[^/]*/\\)*\\(.*\\)" ,(concat
      autosave-dir "\\1") t))
```

Answer (score 4):

The dot-hash-files are created by Emacs as a lock to avoid concurrent modification of a file. Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html) does not mention the possibility of changing the default location of those files:

> The file lock is really a file, a symbolic link with a special name,
>   stored in the same directory as the file you are editing.

Comment: It's not really "unfortunate" -- the mechanism *needs* to be user-agnostic. Any ability to relocate those locks would be counter-productive, unless you could guarantee that everyone was using the same configuration.

Comment: @phils You're right of course, but it's in so far unfortunate that christopherbalz will not be able to achieve what he's after.

Comment: How about telling Emacs to rollback any operations that are currently requiring the lock?

Comment: Isn't the '.#' file specific to Emacs?  If so, then what other concurrent access issues besides other Emacs instances would there be?  For example, in my use case, I don't have other Emacs instances that I need to protect against modifying my locked file.  But I do have Java programs that crash when they hit '.#' files.  So it would be great to be able to put them off in a different location than the default.

Comment: The use case would be multiple users accessing the same file (through Emacs) in a shared folder. If you're sure that this case does not apply to you, you might try putting the following in your .emacs file to prevent lock files to be written: `(fmakunbound 'lock-buffer)`

Comment: It may be a nice feature, but it's annoying enough to make me consider not using emacs any more.  And I'm a total aficionado-- all these years I thought it was because I was configuring it wrong.  That fact that it's a "feature" kind of sucks.

Comment: @Thomas tried `fmakunbound` with no luck unfortunately-- any ideas?

Comment: See solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974060/4869 for Emacs 24.3 : `(setq create-lockfiles nil)`