# Is it possible to prevent emacs from creating " .#files "

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

[image]

Is it possible to prevent emacs from creating these " .#files " when editing unsaved files?

I acknowledge the file disappears once I save the changes to the file I'm editing.

However my question still remains the same, is it possible for emacs to simply not create such a file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738170/why-does-emacs-create-temporary-symbolic-links-for-modified-files

Comment: perfect. Thank you. I didn't know what it was called.