# can't get rid of backup autosave files [#, ~]

Tags: emacs

I have this configuration but emacs still creates autosave files, which is driving me crazy. Please HELP.

```
;; no backup files
;; get rid of backup and autosave files
(defvar user-temporary-file-directory
  (concat temporary-file-directory user-login-name "/"))
(make-directory user-temporary-file-directory t)
(setq backup-by-copying t)
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `(("." . ,user-temporary-file-directory)
        (,tramp-file-name-regexp nil)))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix
      (concat user-temporary-file-directory ".auto-saves-"))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,user-temporary-file-directory t)))
(setq make-backup-files nil)
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

Comment: Does this help?  `(setq backup-inhibited t)`  Documentation:  *If non-nil, backups will be inhibited. This variable is intended for use by making it local to a buffer, but it is not an automatically buffer-local variable.  This variable's value is permanent if it is given a local binding.*

Comment: You may also be interested in adjusting the variable for `lockfiles`?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23317002/2112489