# hidden autosave file error: no such file or directory

Tags: macos, file, emacs, terminal, autosave

I was editing an emacs file abc, and prior to saving, had a crash.  There is now a file .#abc, and I would like to find out what is in that file, to perhaps recover what I was working on.

I know the file is there because when I type

> ls -a

it lists

> .#abc

However, when I type

> more ".#abc"

or simply

> more .#abc

I get the error

> .#abc: No such file or directory

The same error occurs with cp in place of more.

How do I see what is in that file?  Why does ls list it and then other commands can't find the file?

(Is .#abc actually an alias file?  If so, how would I know that?  And how, nevertheless, do I see the content of it, even if this is only what it is an alias to?)

[Note: I do not want to use emacs to try to find out what is in the file or restore it, because the situation is somewhat more complicated than described: the above is all occurring inside a Time Machine backup, which I need to access because of an emacs autosave overwrite problem on the primary file.  I don't want to have the same problem occur on the backup of the autosave file!]

This is all on Mac OS10.8.4.

Comment: What do you see if you type `ls -la`?

Comment: try with `more .\#abc`. # is the shell character for comments, everything after that to the end of the line is ignored.

Comment: 'ls -la' revealed that the file was a symbolic link (and to what it linked), as explained also in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas autosave files use a tilde `~`, lock-files use a dot number-sign `.#`:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html

Creation of lock-files can be disabled with the following setting:

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974060/2112489