# Emacs' autosave files and ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, emacs, ember-cli

I'm new using ember-cli and I use emacs as my editor. Anytime I modify a file, I get this error in the ember server console

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/user/projects/ember-cli-101/example-1/borrowers/app/routes/.#friends.js'
```

and then I have to restart my server. I have read that I have to modify my gulpfile.js but I don't have any in my project.

What do I have to do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem in Broccoli, see https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli/issues/154

As a temporary solution, you might [disable file locking in Emacs completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738170/why-does-emacs-create-temporary-symbolic-links-for-modified-files).